# Power BI Filtering issue caused by If statement measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Apologies up front, this is going to take a second to explain but I'd rather be thorough so the problem is clear. The main problem that I am having is that people are not being properly filtered out of a matrix that I am using and I believe I have isolated the problem to some measures that I have written. Below is a picture of what I'm working with (I guess you'll have to follow the link):

[image: Full Matrix]

My problem is that when I try to apply a filter using the slicer, you would expect the available names to be filtered out of the matrix based on if they fall under the particular team leader or director selected. However, they do not, as seen in this picture:

[image: Filtered using slicer]

Clearly, people are not being filtered out because there are still values in the AnswerRatePass column and the SurveyScorePass column. I will focus on just AnswerRatePass to cut the problem in half. The purpose of AnswerRatePass is to output text to identify if the Answer Rate of a person exceeded their goal, met the goal, or missed the goal. My code for AnswerRatePass is:

```
AnswerRatePass = if([AnswerRateGoal] = 1,"Exceed",
if([AnswerRateGoal]=0,"Achieved","Missed"))
```

As you surely noticed, [AnswerRatePass] is using the value of [AnswerRateGoal]  to determine what to do. I use this because it sort of simplifies the code for my Recommendation measure, which assesses if a person met their goals for both criteria, meaning we suggest to promote this person, or what their case is. My code for AnswerRateGoal is:

```
AnswerRateGoal =   
if(ISBLANK([AnswerRate]),0,  
    if(values(TMD[Title])="Executive",  
        if([AnswerRate]>=.94,1,  
            if([AnswerRate]>=.92,0,-1)),  
        if(values(TMD[Title])="President's Club",  
            if([AnswerRate]>=.96,1,  
            if([AnswerRate]>=.94,0,-1)),  
            if([AnswerRate]>=.96,0,-1)  
        )))
```

If these measures (AnswerRatePass, SurveyScorePass, and Recommendation) are removed from the matrix, the slicers work exactly as expected. So, long story short, what I'm pretty sure I need is some sort of filter for these measures so that these values will disappear when using a slicer that doesn't apply to that person, allowing the individual person to also be filtered out by the slicer as well. Unless someone has a different idea, I'm pretty sure that's what I need but I haven't been able to come up with a way to do it. I'm open to any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I've seen this before. I think what you want is for `AnswerRatePass` to return a blank if `AnswerRate` is blank. Try something like this:

```
AnswerRatePass =
IF(
    ISBLANK([AnswerRate]),
    BLANK(),
    IF(           
        [AnswerRateGoal] = 1,
        "Exceed",
        IF(
            [AnswerRateGoal] = 0,
            "Achieved",
            "Missed"
        )
    )
)
```

---

*Side note:* The [`SWITCH` function](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) is often a cleaner approach then nested `IF` functions.

Comment: You are the man. This worked 100%. I kept trying to use filters and calculate in different ways and obviously it didn't get me anywhere. I've never used switch before but tried it out and it is definitely a much simpler formula. Thanks for the tip!